# Replacing Large.jpg with t500x500.jpg

Tags: php

Currently I am messing around with SoundClouds API, I am trying to make it so that when I pull the art-work using the following code.

```
<div class="artwork_url">
<a href="'.$content[$x]['artwork_url'].'" style="text-decoration: none; color: #365899;">View Image</a>
</div>
```

It will return [link to desired format](https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000163330482-gympi5-t500x500.jpg) but instead it returns something that looks similar to this [link to image giving me problems](https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000163330482-gympi5-large.jpg).

Any help would be very much appreciated. 
Here's a link to [SoundClouds API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) provided you need reference.

Comment: Can you do a var_dump() of $content[$x] pls ?

Comment: What does `$content[$x]['artwork_url']` currently return? Can you not just add the dimensions after the image url? `<a href="'.$content[$x]['artwork_url'].'-t500x500.jpg"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation `The URL is pointing to the format large by default. If you want to use a different format you have to replace large with the specific format name in the image URL:`

This should work :

**PHP**

```
str_replace('large', 't500x500', $content[$x]['artwork_url'])
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="artwork_url">
  <a href="'.str_replace('large', 't500x500', $content[$x]['artwork_url']).'" style="text-decoration: none;      color: #365899;">View Image</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I checked the docs, I think replacing `large.jpg` or `large.` should be safer. Or even `-large.`